# Run all possible combination of page filters in a pivot + VBA + Dynamic Solution

Tags: vba, dynamic, excel, combinations

I am trying to create a macro that is dynamic and runs through all possible combination of page filters and produce reports.

Right now, I just have two filters: AccountManager and CostCenter and the Macro below runs through all values of AccountManager and their corresponding value of CostCenter and prepares a report.

```
Sub Run_All_Reports()
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PF As PivotField
    Dim PI As PivotItem, PI2 As PivotItem

    Sheets("Pivot").Activate
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Budget")

    For Each PI In PT.pageFields(1).PivotItems
        PT.pageFields(1).CurrentPage = PI.Name
        For Each PI2 In PT.pageFields(2).PivotItems
            PT.pageFields(2).CurrentPage = PI2.Name
            Call Run_Report
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I do not know how to extend this functionality to be dynamic, i.e. it reads how many page filters are present and then prepares report for each possible combination.

Lets say, I introduce another filter - Area. Then it should produce reports for all possible combination. An example below:

```
John, Marketing, London
John, Marketing, NewYork
John, Sales, London
Sam, Sales, London
Sam, Sales, NewYork
```

Not sure if I am clear enough. I have tried to look all over but couldn't find a solution. I got asked this question for 2 page filters and I have implemented the above solution but I have a headache since yesterday because I want it to be dynamic in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me!

This loops through all the possible combination of page fields. I am sure a more optimised version exists. But I am not from a computing background and this was one problem that interested me

```
Sub All_Comb()
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PI As PivotItem, PI2 As PivotItem
    Dim totPF As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim elemCountArray() As Integer

    Sheets("Pivot").Activate
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Budget")
    totPF = PT.PageFields.Count

    ReDim elemCountArray(0 To totPF)
    For i = 1 To totPF
        elemCountArray(i) = PT.PageFields(i).PivotItems.Count
    Next i

    For i = 1 To totPF
        For y = 1 To elemCountArray(i)
            PT.PageFields(i).CurrentPage = PT.PageFields(i).PivotItems(y).Name
            If (i < totPF) Then
                Call SetUpFields(PT, i + 1, elemCountArray(i + 1), totPF, elemCountArray())
            End If
        Next y
    Next i
End Sub

Sub SetUpFields(PT As PivotTable, PFid As Integer, elemCount As Integer, totPF As Integer, elemCountArray() As Integer)
    For y = 1 To elemCount
        PT.PageFields(PFid).CurrentPage = PT.PageFields(PFid).PivotItems(y).Name
        If (PFid < totPF) Then
                Call SetUpFields(PT, PFid + 1, elemCountArray(PFid + 1), totPF, elemCountArray())
        End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive procedure, something like the following

e.g.

```
Sub RunForALlItems(PT as pivotTable, count as integer)
numFields= PT.pageFields.count
for each PI in PT.pageFields(num).PivotItems
   PT.pageFields(num).CurrentPage = PI.Name
   if (num=numFields) then
      call run_Report
   elseif (num<numFields) then
      call RunForAllItems(PT, count+1)
   end if
next
end sub
```

And then call it with

```
RunForAllItems(PT, 1)
```

**I haven't tested it**, but it should - with minor tweaking - work